# How to read all collection from mongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb

If i want read all collection of my data database (mongoDB) I use the method find() "print(db.collecion.find())" we done error

the error :

'Database' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'find' method on a 'MongoClient' object it is failing because no such method exists.

how to fix it?
**the code source :**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo import *
import os
import pprint

mongodb_host = 'localhost'
mongo_port = '27017'

client = MongoClient(mongodb_host + ':'+mongo_port)
db = client['test']
cl=db.client
try:

  pprint.pprint(cl.find())
except Exception as e:
  print ('this connection or insert are wrong.')
  print (e)
```

**the error :**

> 'Database' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'find'
>   method on a 'MongoClient' object it is failing because no such method
>   exists.

*how to fix it?*

Comment: Please check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Add your code , what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

After using find you need to make a loop in it for records.Then you should be able to retrieve them.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.db_name
for document in db.get_collection('collection_name').find():
    print(document)
```

From your second request I assumed you want an output like this.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from prettytable import PrettyTable
client = MongoClient()
db = client.kliffot
table = PrettyTable(['Mail', 'Timezone'])
for document in db.get_collection('user').find():
   table.add_row([document['email'], document['timezone']])
print(table)

"""Output sample"""
+-------------------+----------+
|        Mail       | Timezone |
+-------------------+----------+
| guray@kliffot.com |   UTC    |
| guray@kliffot.com |   UTC    |
+-------------------+----------+
```

If so you can use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable library for it via

```
pip3 install PrettyTable or pip install PrettyTable
```

depending on your python version.

Comment: but i want show it like attribute in the table not like dictionary . how to do that please ?

Comment: @NoussaierGrayaa I have made some changes on the answer.Is this what you want to do ?

Comment: i want to do a phyton application with interfaces(tkinter)
graphs for managing car rentals using MongoDB  
Develop interfaces for car management:
o Add a car,
o Modify a car,
o Delete a car,
o List cars with availability status.
- Develop interfaces for customer management:
o Add a customer,
o Modify a customer,
o Delete a customer,
o List clients with state.
- Develop interfaces for managing car rentals:
o Show cars rented by customers